# For a convex function, prove that the line segment increases as you move the $x$ values further out on both sides.

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function prove that if $a<b$, then $\frac{f(-a)+f(a)}2<\frac{f(-b)+f(b)}2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality in strict form is false (take $f=0$).

The non-strict inequality can be proven as follows. The point $a$ belongs to the interval $[-b,+b]$, so there is $\lambda\in (0,1)$ such that
$$
a = \lambda b + (1-\lambda)(-b).
$$
Then
$$
-a = \lambda(- b) + (1-\lambda)(+b).
$$
Using the convexity of $f$ gives
$$
f(-a) + f(a) \le \big[ \lambda f(-b) + (1-\lambda)f(b)\big] + \big[ \lambda f(b) + (1-\lambda)f(-b)\big] = f(b)+f(-b).
$$

Comment: Good one ! I think , we can extend this Case [[ $(-b,b)$ containing $(-a,a)$ ]] to the more general Case [[ $(A,D)$ containing $(B,C)$ ]] with little tweaking !